# Tricky regular expression, lots of newlines and whitespaces

Tags: c#, regex

I've been trying to do this for a few hours now without luck. I've tried several RegExp patterns but here I am, asking for help now. This is the text

```html
 <span class="bold">Life:</span>
                                    </div>
                                    10200 / 10200                                </li>
                                <li>
```

What I'm trying to get is 10200 / 10200. I haven't had any luck. I'm trying to do this in C# by the way. Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: Use a DOM-parser to parse and get content from HTML. RegExes are not made for HTML.

Comment: I have to do this using RegEx.

Comment: Says who? Use the right tool for the right job. And regular expressions are not the right tool for parsing HTML.

Comment: Beware, this [could lead to severe sickness](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3764814). Or just use the `(\d+)\s*/\s*(\d+)` regex. :)

Comment: What exactly do you want? If you want the contents of a HTML tag, use a HTML parser. If you want to extract text like "number / number", use regex. If you want "10200 / 10200", use "return "10200 / 10200"".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is not the best tool but you can use this:

```
(?sx)
(?<=
   <span class="bold">Life:</span> \s* </div> \s*
)
[^<]+
```